# Create a sideshow/carousel navigation based on number of list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create my sideshow nav based on the number of slides.

```javascript
var navList = $('<li class="cItem"><a href="#"></a></li>');
var carouselItems = el.find('li');

for (var i = 0, len = carouselItems.length; i < len; i++){
  var e = carouselItems[i];
  options.navigation.append(navList);
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: what is problem with this code?

Comment: Please include a question, along with a better description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what are you trying to achieve, but if you want to get all the elements and do something with each of them, you can try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $ el = $("li");
   $el.each(function(){
       $(this).appendTo("div");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this JQuery Plugin

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/